When are we required to add isolates as part of the ergm model and how to interpretate the coefficient
Recently, I am trying to perform network analysis by modeling a network of companies with ERGM. When i was looking into some popular terms to be added in the model, I come across with isolates term, and therefore I wondered how I should interpret the coefficient of isolates term (when it is negative or positive)
I was reading the following link to help making interpretations, but it does not include the interpretation of ergm terms. https://github.com/eehh-stanford/SNA-workshop/blob/master/ergm-predictions.md#more-realistic-change-statistics
